# HTTP Error 401.0 when debugging ASP MVC project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis

I recently took over an ASP MVC project at work, and when trying to debug in Visual Studio 2010 I receive an HTTP Error 401.0. I'm completely new to using ASP MVC, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thx!

Detailed Error Information:

Module

ManagedPipelineHandler

Notification

ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler

System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler

Error Code

0x00000000

Requested URL

localhost:2574/ (EDIT: I removed the 'http://' from the front of this URL due to an error from StackOverflow when I tried to post the question)

Physical Path

C:\Projects\sym_SPAIN_INT_NEAROD\sym_SPAIN\SPAIN

Logon Method

Anonymous

Logon User

Anonymous

Request Tracing Directory

C:\Users\nearod\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\SPAIN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work with Neal, and thought we'd better post the answer.  This application had changed the authentication mode from Form to Windows in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Which ran fine on Windows XP.  On Windows 7, it returned a 401.  We found the issue in Project Properties (not the one when you right-click the project, but the one where you click the project name and click the Properties window icon.)  In the Properties window, there is an item for Windows Authentication.  This was set to "Disabled".  Changing to "Enabled" fixed the problem.